# Add ipv6 route so packets go to eth0

Tags: ip

I have 2 VM Ubuntu 14.04 in VirtualBox.
They are connected in internal network.
One Ubuntu is sending multicast data (via VLC) and one is receiving.

I added this in both VM's so it works via IPV4

```
ip r add 224.0.0.0/8 dev eth0
```

In VLC i am streaming into 224.255.1.1

I need to check even if ipv6 multicast will work. 
So i need to convert the IPV4 to IPV6 and than add ipv6 route on both VM's.

Comment: I don't even know where to start. Adding multicast addresses IPv4 to interfaces isn't something you do. Neither you do that for IPv6. And no, you don't "convert the IPv4 address to IPv6". You can use `ssmping` to test both IPv4 and IPv6 multicast; it will use the proper protocol to register multicast sender/receivers. And please read up on how multicast works.